# list subfolders using applescript

Tags: applescript, finder

This is my first applescript.  I thought I'd do something simple like navigating to a folder using a path and listing the subfolders...Unfortunately, I can't figure it out :-)

Here is what I've tried so far:

The first try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_folder to POSIX path of "Users:MyName:Doc"
    log the_folder
    set folder_list to every item of folder the_folder
    log folder_list 
end tell
```

This produces an error:
"Finder got an error: Can't get folder "/Users/MyName/Doc".

Could someone please:
1. Explain to me what I'm doing wrong.
2. Provide an example that works.

Thanks in advance.

btw the folder does exist on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Oops! It appears that I have given you the wrong information so I will give you the correct information.

The command `POSIX path of` requires a complete alias reference. By that I mean supplying the full file reference (i.e. `<your_disk_name>:Users:<your_user_name>:somefolder:`). Make sure that if you're referring to a folder that you end the reference with a colon (i.e. `Macintosh HD:Users:`). An improved version would look like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set the_folder to (POSIX path of ("<your_disk_name>:Users:<your_user_name>:Doc:") as alias) as alias
  set folder_list to every item of the_folder
end tell
```

## OPTIONAL

To coerce a `POSIX` path (i.e. `/Users/<your_user_name>/somefolder`) back into an `alias`, two conversions are needed.

**Conversion 1:** The first step is to convert the reference into a file reference. To do this, place the words `as POSIX file` after the reference, like so:

```
"/Users/<your_user_name>/somefolder" as POSIX file
```

This code procudes a file reference in this form: `file "<your_disk_name>:Users:<your_user_name>:somefolder:"`

**Conversion 2**: Add a second coercion, `as alias`, to the end of the reference...

```
"/Users/<your_user_name>/somefolder" as POSIX file as alias
```

This code produces an actual alias reference: `alias "<your_disk_name>:Users:<your_user_name>:somefolder:`

If you have any questions, just ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

Posix paths are paths you use at the command line and are "/" delimited. Applescript paths are ":" separated so just use those. Try this script to see what the path should look like...

```
set folderPath to (choose folder) as text
```